# Should you rely on implicit type contracts for function returns types, or always make it explicit?

Tags: typescript

Say you're using an external library, that includes type declarations, and it has a function like:

```
function foo(x: number) : string {
   //implementation
}
```

Somewhere in our code we're calling this with:

```
function ourFunction() {
    return foo(1); 
}
```

or with the return type explicit :

```
function ourFunction() : string {
    return foo(1); 
}
```

Typescript is smart enough to infer that the return type of this function is `string`.

So I don't *have* to declare the return type of `ourFunction`, but I can.

The question is - should I?

The way I'm thinking about this is - that if I make the return type explicit, then I later change the implementation of the function - if I accidentally change the return type in the process, that's going to make me immediately aware of the problem.

On the otherhand - with the code I'm currently writing, I'm basically just copy pasting the return types from that external function that I'm calling.

Are there any general principles that help with making this decision?

Comment: If you want to, you can make the return type of `ourFunction` into `ReturnType<typeof foo>` so that if `foo` changes then the type will automatically change. Admittedly this makes more sense if `foo` is your function meaning it is more likely to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most type inferred languages, you are encouraged to write explicit types for all function arguments and return types, and at key points in function bodies. As you surmised, this helps ensure you implemented the function as you expected, and it also acts as a sort of documentation for the programmer. They don't have to read the entire function to know how to use it.

The "key points" inside the function are at the programmer's discretion, and those more familiar with the language tend to write fewer of them, but my rule of thumb is to add a type annotation if I have to read more than a line or two to figure out what the type is.

Also, many people will put a lot more type annotations when they are first writing a brand new implementation, then take them out to reduce the clutter once they are done. This, again, is because of the extra help it provides in getting it correct. Later on during debugging or maintenance, you might find it useful to add an occasional type annotation back in. If I feel the need to do so, I take that as a sign that I should probably leave it in permanently, which is another way I identify "key points."

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are using typescript *because* you want the benefits of strong typing.

So your `ourFunction` is part of a class, which maybe implements an interface or uses inheritance and will *need* a type, regardless of how the concrete implementation works.

Also, Say the library changes from string to int at some stage. Classes which use your wrapper will probably need changing, even if they still compile.

By specifiying string in your wrapper, those classes will now generate a compile time rather than runtime error. Which is desired behaviour.